Change input disabled status by button
I want to change all input boxes from disabled to enabled by pressing the button 'change'
What is the most effective way in React and how would it look like?
return (
<div className='container-background-user'>    
  <div className='container-wrapper-user'>
    <div className='wrapper-user'>
        <div className='profile-picture-user'>
          <h1>Profilbild</h1>
        </div>
        <form className='form-user' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <h1>PROFILDATEN</h1>
          <div className='input-group'>
              <div className='first-row-user'>
                <div className='input-user'>
                  <label>Profilname</label>
                  <input id='userNameShow' name='username_input' disabled='disabled'></input>
                </div>
                <div className='input-user'>
                  <label>Geburtsdatum</label>
                  <input id='userDateShow' type='date' name='username_birthday_input' disabled='disabled'></input>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className='second-row-user'>
              <div className='input-user'>
                  <label>E-mail</label>
                  <input type='email' id='userDataEmail' name='username_email_input' disabled='disabled'></input>
                </div>
                <div className='input-user'>
                  <label>Passwort</label>
                  <input type='password' id='userDataPassword' name='username_password_input' disabled='disabled'></input>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div className='third-row-user'>
            <div className='button-user'>
              <button className='change'>ÄNDERN</button>
              <button type='submit'>SPEICHERN </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  );

Thanks for your help

What you're looking for is using a State. This is generally used for cases like this when you expect a variable to change and want relevant components to re-render with the changed variable automatically.
Below I've adapted your code to use this as follows:
const [disableFields, setDisableFields] = useState(true)

defines disableFields, which is the variable your form fields will refer to for if they should be disabled or not as well as setDisableFields(value) which we will use to update the value. This naming is explained here. useState(true) means we initialize this value to be true so the user has to click on ÄNDERN to enable the fields.
Now for each input we can replace disabled='disabled' with disabled={disableFields}. React will dynamically fill in the current value of disableFields there and enable/disable the field accordingly.
On your ÄNDERN button, we add the properties
<button type='button' onClick={() => setDisableFields(!disableFields)}>

We define the onClick function to call setDisableFields, here using it to toggle between values. If you just need to enable it when clicking the button this can of course be replaced with setDisableFields(true). We add type='button' to prevent the button's default behavior, as is explained in this answer.
import React, {useState} from 'react';

export function App(props) {
  const [disableFields, setDisableFields] = useState(true)
  return (
<div className='container-background-user'>    
  <div className='container-wrapper-user'>
    <div className='wrapper-user'>
        <div className='profile-picture-user'>
          <h1>Profilbild</h1>
        </div>
        <form className='form-user'>
          <h1>PROFILDATEN</h1>
          <div className='input-group'>
              <div className='first-row-user'>
                <div className='input-user'>
                  <label>Profilname</label>
                  <input id='userNameShow' name='username_input' disabled={disableFields}></input>
                </div>
                <div className='input-user'>
                  <label>Geburtsdatum</label>
                  <input id='userDateShow' type='date' name='username_birthday_input' disabled={disableFields}></input>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className='second-row-user'>
              <div className='input-user'>
                  <label>E-mail</label>
                  <input type='email' id='userDataEmail' name='username_email_input' disabled={disableFields}></input>
                </div>
                <div className='input-user'>
                  <label>Passwort</label>
                  <input type='password' id='userDataPassword' name='username_password_input' disabled={disableFields}></input>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div className='third-row-user'>
            <div className='button-user'>
              <button className='change' type='button' onClick={() => setDisableFields(!disableFields)}>ÄNDERN</button>
              <button type='submit'>SPEICHERN </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  );

}

